# Why does the distance image has to be masked?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, mask

Based on:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html

```
% Compute the stroke width variation metric
strokeWidthValues = distanceImage(skeletonImage);
```

Why does the distanceImage has to be masked by skeleton image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stroke width is obtained as the distance to the background evaluated at the skeleton pixels (also known as the medial axis). The distance at other pixels is of no interest.